# Scaling variables for model selection. Unscaling for final model?

Tags: binomial-distribution, biostatistics, glmm, scales, centering

I struggle with the following question:
I had to scale variables for model selection as they were in very different units and the model struggled to converge. Now that I have a final model the variables that are left in the model are variables that do actually have the same units.
I would find it much easier to interpret and to present the model in its unscaled version, as far as I understand scaling does not change the variables itself, so am I allowed to just compute the final model without the scaling and preseent the results? Will it be the same?
And what does it mean for comparing the odds ratios, as far as I understand scaling will make them compareable, but as they have the same units aren´t they compareable even without the scaling?

Comment: If by "scaling" you mean multiplying by a constant, then, yes, you can go back to the original units. If you went from kilometers to centimeters, you can go back by the inverse process. 

However, the whole process worries me. I would like to know more details of how you did the selection and why it struggled to converge. Unless the units are really odd, that seems strange. And model selection is often done badly. 

Was the problem rounding error?  But then, how are the original units easier to interpret?

And if you did some more complex form of scaling, well, then it's complicated.

Comment: I did use only scale and center so original (value-mean)/sd. I think the convergence was only due to the model being already at its end in terms of variables included and scaling aided to help, as some of the values were between 0 and 1 while other went up into the thousands with a huge spread. I used backwards selection and confirmed my results with automaticated model selection using dredge comparing AIC.

Comment: Backwards selection is not good. Neither is forward or stepwise. Many threads about this on this site.  If you HAVE to use an automated method, LASSO isn't too bad. But using your brain is better.

Comment: Thank you but that does not answer my question, maybe I will use another method next time. I have selected my models carefully with the advise of my professors,